# Ошибка при использовании переменной python

Tags: python, python-3.x, переменные

Из-за чего связана эта ошибка?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "shootandeat.py", line 64, in <module>
    macronow()
  File "shootandeat.py", line 17, in macronow
    if macrostatus == 0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'macrostatus' referenced before assignment
```

Мой код:

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time
import random
ht = "NON"
macrostatus = 0
settingsvisible = 1
fkstatus = "OFF"
msstatus = "OFF"
cd = "0"
cdfk = "0"
nowslot = "0"
nowfkslot = "0"

def macronow():
    if macrostatus == 0:
        print(" enable macro:   [1]")
        if settingsvisible == 1:
            print(" macro settings: [2]")
            print("")
        if settingsvisible == 0:
            print("")
    if macrostatus == 1:
        print(" disable macro:  [1]")
        if settingsvisible == 1:
            print(" macro settings: [2]")
            print("")
        if settingsvisible == 0:
            print("")
    if macrostatus >= 2:
        macrostatus = 0
        os.system("msg %username% SHOOT&EAT: macro reloaded")

def settings():
    print("  FirstKit:    [" +fkstatus+ "] [3]")
    print("  Hotkey:      [" +ht+ "] [4]")
    print("")
    print("  Now slot:    ["+nowslot+"] [5]")
    print("  Now fk slot: ["+nowfkslot+"] [6]")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("  Cooldown:    [" +cd+ "s] [7]")
    print("  Cooldown fk: [" +cdfk+ "s] [8]")
    print("")
def main():
    titleprotect = str(random.randint(0,100000))
    os.system("title SHOOTandEAT: [" +titleprotect+ "]")
    os.system("cls")
    print("")
    print("         __                __  ___                __ ")
    print("   _____/ /_  ____  ____  / /_( _ )   ___  ____ _/ /_")
    print("  / ___/ __ \/ __ \/ __ \/ __/ __ \/|/ _ \/ __ `/ __/")
    print(" (__  ) / / / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ /_/  </  __/ /_/ / /_  ")
    print("/____/_/ /_/\____/\____/\__/\____/\/\___/\__,_/\__/  ")
    print("                >| SHOOT&EAT |<")
    print("")

os.system("color 0e")
menuwhile = 0
while menuwhile < 1:
    macrostatus = 0
    main()
    macronow()
    menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "1" and macrostatus == 0:
        menuwhile = 2
        macrostatus = 0
        macrostatus = macrostatus + 1
        main()
        macronow()
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "1" and macrostatus == 1:
        menuwhile = 2
        macrostatus = macrostatus - 1
        main()
        macronow()
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "2" and settingsvisible == 1:
        menuwhile = 2
        settingsvisible = settingsvisible - 1
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()  
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "3" and settingsvisible == 0:
        menuwhile = 2
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        nowfkslot = input("   Slot fk > ")
        cdfk = input("   Cooldown fk > ")
        fkstatus = "ON"
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "4" and settingsvisible == 0:
        menuwhile = 2
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        ht = input("   New Hotkey > ")
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "5" and settingsvisible == 0:
        menuwhile = 2
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        nowslot = input("   New slot > ")
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "6" and settingsvisible == 0:
        menuwhile = 2
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        nowfkslot = input("   New fk slot > ")
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "7" and settingsvisible == 0:
        menuwhile = 2
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        cd = input("   New cooldown > ")
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
    if menu == "8" and settingsvisible == 0:
        menuwhile = 2
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        cdfk = input("   New fk cooldown > ")
        main()
        macronow()
        settings()
        menu = input("Ur choice > ")
```

Прошу обратить внимание, что при добавлении `macrostatus = 0` в `def`, то будет работать, но мне необходимо что бы переменная не была все время 0, а могла изменятся из других функций

Comment: В приведенном коде указанная ошибка не возникает. Покажите весь код.

Comment: @Эникейщик, изменил тему. Теперь полностью весь код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в функции добавь global там где надо 
допустим

```
def macronow():
    global macrostatus
    global settingsvisible
    if macrostatus == 0:
        print(" enable macro:   [1]")
        if settingsvisible == 1:
            print(" macro settings: [2]")
            print("")
        if settingsvisible == 0:
            print("")
    if macrostatus == 1:
        print(" disable macro:  [1]")
        if settingsvisible == 1:
            print(" macro settings: [2]")
            print("")
        if settingsvisible == 0:
            print("")
    if macrostatus >= 2:
        macrostatus = 0
        os.system("msg %username% SHOOT&EAT: macro reloaded")
```

Comment: В функции нет переменной macrostatus вот из за чего оно так